# How to read when i download that attachment my app need to recognize my custom extension file in android

Tags: android

Here, I have a image file that i have to compressed into zip file and change the extension.
and am attaching zip file to email and sending. Later after download that custom extension file, My app need to recognise, and read the content in that zip file. so how to handle these.
provide basic idea step by step process.
And also i have seen, for example in android device, if want to open a image file like xyz.png or xyz.jpg, when I click on those images it ask me to open image file through, gallery or photos or flicker, or any other app for just once or every time. So i would like to show my app in those category. give me idea how to achieve.

How to create my custom extension file, compress in to zip file, attach to email, and finally when i dowmload that attachment my app need to recognize my custom extension file in android

Answer (score 0):

Try this, in your AndroidManifest.xml put those lines in the Activity you want to use to open your attachment:

```
<activity android:name="com.my.package.MyCoolActivity">
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:mimeType="my/mimetype" android:path="*.*\\.my_extension" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then in your Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

  Uri data = getIntent().getData();
  if (data !=null) {
    /* Do whatever you want with the Uri*/
  }
}
```